# Erro 500 ao submeter um formulário com validação em ajax e laravel fortify

Tags: ajax, laravel

Estou a tentar criar um formulário simples de registo em laravel fortify e usando validação com ajax. O formulário quando é submetido insere os valores na base de dados como pretendido, porém acaba por **não redirecionar para a página de usuário após esse registo**, como pretendido, e aparece este **erro** que não sei como resolver: **"register:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"**

O **formulário**:

```
<form class="multisteps-form__form" id="wizard" method="POST" action="{{route('register')}}">
    @csrf
    <div class="step-content-field">    
    <div class="form-inner-area">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control "  placeholder="First Name" required>
        <div class="text-danger error" data-error="firstname"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inner-area">
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control "  placeholder="Last Name" required>
        <div class="text-danger error" data-error="lastname"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inner-area">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control "  id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <div class="text-danger error" data-error="email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inner-area">
        <label>Mobile:</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control " id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required>
        <div class="text-danger error" data-error="mobile"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inner-area">
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control "  id="country" placeholder="Country" required>
        <div class="text-danger error" data-error="country"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inner-area">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control "  id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-inner-area">
        <label>Confirm password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control"  id="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password" required>
        
    </div>
    <span>The password must be at least 8 characters and contain at least one uppercase character, one number, and one special character.</span>
    </div>
   <div class="actions">
      <ul>
       <li><span class="js-btn-prev" title="BACK"><i class="fa fa-arrow- 
       left"></i> BACK </span></li>
      <li><button type="submit" title="SUBMIT">SUBMIT <i class="fa fa- 
      arrow-right"></i></button></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

O **script** em ajax:

```
<script>
    $('#wizard').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.error').html('');
    $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    method: $(this).attr('method'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success(response)
    {
    console.log('User created successfully.');
    },
    error(error)
    {
    let errors = error.responseJSON.errors
    for(let key in errors)
    {
        let errorDiv = $(`.error[data-error="${key}"]`);
        if(errorDiv.length )
        {
            errorDiv.text(errors[key][0]);
        }
        }
    }
});
});
    </script>
```

E o controller **CreateNewUser** do fortify:

```
class CreateNewUser implements CreatesNewUsers
{
    use PasswordValidationRules;

    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique(User::class),
            ],
            'mobile' => ['required', 'int'],
            'country' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();

        $user = User::create([
            'firstname' => $input['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $input['lastname'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'mobile' => $input['mobile'],
            'country' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            
        ]);
            $user->notify(new WelcomeEmailNotification());

            return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
}
```

Comment: e onde está o código que faz o redirect?

Comment: Por estar criando, pode ser o notify com algum problema ou no retorno.. Sugiro que vá nos logs em 'storage/logs' e veja se tem algum erro por lá.